Do all toral maps have a dense set of periodic points on the torus?
I'm aware of the result when we have a hyperbolic toral automorphism, but I was wondering if it holds in a more general context.
If all we have is an $n \times n$ integer matrix $A$ defining a toral map, with no guarantee of it being invertible (i.e. that $\det(A) = \pm 1$), is there a dense set of periodic points on $\mathbb{T}^n = \mathbb{R}^n/ \mathbb{Z}^n$?
The proof from the toral automorphism case relies on inverting $A$, so is there a way to still get a dense set of periodic points without doing that?

For instance, if $det(A)=0$, the subset of periodic points will not be dense in $T^n$.
